# Immediately evaluate multiple lines of code at same time in rails console when using pry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry, pry-rails

Suppose we have `pry` installed, open the rails console, and run

```
times = [1, 5, 10, 30, 72].sample(1)[0]
nums = *(1..72)
num_sample = nums.sample(times)
```

Evaluation stops after line 2 (since the output of the second line runs off screen and hence the console opens the output):

[image]

How can we get the console to **not** stop executing, but rather display the entirety of the output of one line before executing the next, that is, to execute all lines of code it receives? Is there any way to achieve this without removing the pry-rails gem?

Comment: You can suppress the long output by doing something like this: `nums = *(1..72); nil`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks :) - is there any way to to it without altering code? (e.g. what if you have 2000 lines ) Any global setting ?

Comment: You're going to paste 2000 lines into pry? I don't think so :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev frequently.

Comment: In this case, try this: https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Customization-and-configuration#Config_pager

Comment: @SergioTulentsev works perfectly. Thanks very much! (if you want to make it an answer, I will accept it)

Comment: `pry_instance.config.pager = false` is what worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [disable pry pager](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Customization-and-configuration#Config_pager):

> Disabling paging
> Permanently (in a .pryrc file)
>
> ```
> Pry.config.pager = false
> ```
>
> Temporarily (in a repl session)
>
> ```
> pry_instance.config.pager = false
> ```

Comment: I just went to upvote the question and answer, and realised it was my question and I'd already upvoted the answer. Am I the only one that tries to do this. Is it an anti pattern of some sort? I need to drop multiple lines into the rails console fairly frequently.

Comment: @stevec: just a few days ago _I myself_ googled how to do this, found this answer and tried to upvote it :)

Comment: dude hudreds and thousands of thanks to you, i got mad over last 2-3 days thinking of a way to fix this. i tried to enable infinite scrollback, overriding touchpad from keyboard arrow keys and what now. Thanks much