# Stop ...skipping... SUMMARY OF LESS COMMANDS Commands marked with * may be preceded by a number

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When copying some code (about 50 lines) from a rake task to the rails console, I want it to just run the code in the rails console, but instead this happens. The first part is some results printing to screen, but I have no idea what happens next):

```
 #<Appointment:0x00007fb83eec5358
  id: "0f0e14a6-1645-4a7b-ad61-f799e60ac570",
  doctor_id: 1,
  patient_id: 1,
  start_time: Sun, 24 Jan 2021 13:25:45 UTC +00:00,
  end_time: Sun, 24 Jan 2021 14:25:45 UTC +00:00,
  created_at: Sun, 24 Jan 2021 12:50:45 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sun, 24 Jan 2021 13:10:45 UTC +00:00]
...skipping...


                   SUMMARY OF LESS COMMANDS

      Commands marked with * may be preceded by a number, N.
      Notes in parentheses indicate the behavior if N is given.
      A key preceded by a caret indicates the Ctrl key; thus ^K is ctrl-K.

  h  H                 Display this help.
  q  :q  Q  :Q  ZZ     Exit.
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           MOVING

  e  ^E  j  ^N  CR  *  Forward  one line   (or N lines).
  y  ^Y  k  ^K  ^P  *  Backward one line   (or N lines).
```

What is going on and how do I stop it?

Notes:

- [Here](https://gist.github.com/sudojunior/1ebdc489ebf9eb86f5f32b50c459ac4a) is the full text of what appears
- I tried running `Pry.config.pager = false`  as provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63874477/5783745), but the problem happens despite that.